# Is this hollywood electrocution scenario plausible?

Tags: electricity

As this question is a serious spoiler, I've written the film title below the photos

In the film, a character is sitting on a guardrail in the freezing rain. A high voltage line from a downed telephone pole falls onto the guardrail and electrifies it. The character, sitting maybe fifty feet from the point of electrical contact, drops dead almost immediately.

I was wondering how this could possibly happen. The guardrail is obviously grounded all along its length, and the character is wearing thick gloves and very heavy rubber boots for the storm. Is it possible that the power output of a high voltage line is sufficient to overcome these obstacles and put a lethal current across the heart?

[image: Guardrail, power-line, and character]

[image: Contact with the Guardrail]

[image: His boots]

The Ice storm (1997)

Comment: googling, I find no danger of electrocution from phone lines, mild shocks only, as they carry about 50V with signal surges to 100V. Lightining is another story

Comment: To clarify, as I said in my original post, the wire in question is a residential high-voltage line (~7000 V). Perhaps I shouldn't have called it a "telephone" pole, that's just what we usually call them where I am from. And, by the way, electrical discharge from a storm cloud is spelled "lightning."

Comment: Then yes, there is electrocution from the thousand of volts lines. As for lightning,my brain may know it but my fingers do not

Comment: see this https://www.electrocuted.com/2017/03/12/assume-downed-power-line-capable-of-electrocuting-someone/ it has fences as a danger in the end. Also guard rails are not bulit as ground wires, it is possible their contact to earth through the cement to be iffy.,

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question as:

- The guardrail is electrified
- The guardrail is grounded
- The person is sitting on the guardrail

Under this scenario it's not plausible that the person dies. Electrocution happens if electricity flows *through* the person; if that person's body forms the "path of least resistance". In this case the electric circuit goes from the telephone pole to the guardrail to the ground, and there's clearly a path of least resistance through the guardrail (which as a metal is also a good conductor) without passing through the person's body. The rain makes the person's body wet which lowers its electric resistance, but it won't be to the point where it is lower than the metal's electric resistance.

This question's fundamentally similar to [Do birds get shocked when they sit on wires?](https://www.wonderopolis.org/wonder/do-birds-get-shocked-when-they-sit-on-wires). This quote is relevant:

> It would be a different story if a bird touched the ground while sitting on the wire. That would cause it to get shocked. This would also happen if a bird touched another wire with a different voltage. In these cases, the bird’s body would become a path for electricity. It would move through the bird to reach either the ground or another place with a different voltage. This is why power lines tend to be high in the air with plenty of space between the wires!

Comment: I am largely in agreement on this conclusion. However, I would emphasize that electricity does *not* flow following a "path of least resistance". In parallel circuit configurations current is divided proportional to the inverse of the resistance. If all the current followed this easiest path, a toaster in the tub would pose no danger to a person, because all the current would flow through the water immediately surrounding the heating element, from the hot to the neutral. Some of it, however, takes the long way to ground through the drain, and kills you.